azure synapse bicep code failing with the error Values for request parameters are invalid: keyvaultproperties.keyvaulturi
I have got a synapse workspace bicep code below, trying to add double encryption but currently faced with the error below.Tried different things to no avail, the issue here is that the code was decompiled from an ARM template, so not sure if the key syntax is correct.
key: {
  name: 'default'
  keyVaultUrl: 'https://my-keyvault.vault.azure.net/keys/my-key/xxxxxxxx'

}

{"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deployment-operations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"InvalidValuesForRequestParameters","message":"Values for request parameters are invalid: keyvaultproperties.keyvaulturi."}]}
resource create_synapse_workspace 'Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces@2021-06-01' = {
  name: synapse_workspace_name
  location: location
  tags: my_tags
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned,UserAssigned'
    userAssignedIdentities: {
      '${synapse_identity.id}': {}
    }
  }
  properties: {
    defaultDataLakeStorage: {
      createManagedPrivateEndpoint: false
      accountUrl: accountURL
      filesystem: filesystem
    }
    // encryption: {}

    encryption: {
      cmk: {
        kekIdentity: {
          userAssignedIdentity: mi
          useSystemAssignedIdentity: false
        }
        key: {
          name: 'default'
          keyVaultUrl: 'https://my-keyvault.vault.azure.net/keys/my-key/xxxxxxxx'

        }
      }
    }
    managedVirtualNetwork: 'default'
    managedResourceGroupName: null 
    sqlAdministratorLogin: adminaccount
    sqlAdministratorLoginPassword: adminpassword
    privateEndpointConnections: [
    ]
    managedVirtualNetworkSettings: {
      preventDataExfiltration: false
    }
    workspaceRepositoryConfiguration: {
      accountName: account_name
      collaborationBranch: branch
      repositoryName: repo
      rootFolder: folder
      type: type
    }

    trustedServiceBypassEnabled: false    
    publicNetworkAccess: 'Disabled'
  }

}


The keyVaultUrl have the pattern:
var keyVaultUrl = 'https://${encryptionKeyVaultName}${environment().suffixes.keyvaultDns}/keys/${encryptionKeyName}'
and has the result https://xxxx.vault.azure.net/keys/xxxx but yours is https://my-keyvault.vault.azure.net/keys/my-key/xxxxxxxx
OR
You can set keyvault after synapse workspace been created.
@description('Required. Used to activate the workspace after a customer managed key is provided.')
param isActiveCMK bool

resource cMKKeyVault 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2023-02-01' existing = {
  name: ''

  resource cMKKey 'keys@2023-02-01' existing = {
    name: name
  }
}

resource workspace 'Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces@2021-06-01' existing = {
  name: ''
}

resource key 'Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/keys@2021-06-01' = {
  name: ''
  parent: workspace
  properties: {
    isActiveCMK: isActiveCMK
    keyVaultUrl: cMKKeyVault::cMKKey.properties.keyUri
  }
}

Where I cite.  template1 template2
